# How do I measure the "dispersions" of a group of time series

Tags: correlation, pca, dispersion, divergence

I have a group of time series $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$. I want to measure how much they have "dispersed" over time. i.e. are they moving "more together" in 2023, comparing to 2022. $n$ is about 50. Time series are measured in the same points in time (in fact, daily, so no more than 365 data points a year).

If there are just two time series, then I just measure the correlation of $X_1$ and $X_2$ in two different years. What do I do with $n$ of them?

One thing I can think of is to run a PCA and compare if the first principal component takes up more variance, but it can get messy. For example why don't we look at first two principal components? How do we compare two PCs? I'd like to know if there is a systematic, existing measure.

Comment: How big is $n$, roughly? Three to ten, or hundreds / thousands? // the answer may also depend on which features of the time series you are interested in. Are the time series measured in the same points in time?

Comment: @Ute n is about 50. Time series are measured in the same points in time yes.